# Better way to calculate with two decimals than doing Number(Number("4.22").toFixed(2)) or Math.round(("4.22") * 1e2) / 1e2

Tags: javascript, node.js, currency-formatting

I have a Node.js based backend where I do some simple calculations with currency amounts (two decimals).

Is there a better way to calculate with those than these usually recommended two options:

```
Number(Number("4.22").toFixed(2))
```

or

```
Math.round(("4.22") * 1e2) / 1e2
```

The floats come mostly from the ORM which represents them as strings.

While this is not complicated to handle with a helper function there might be a better way or Node package to do so.

Comment: And changing the data format in your ORM, is not the simplest way ?

Comment: As owner of the Bookshelf.js ORM which I am using actually we will roll this out soon. This question is more about curiosity.